# assertEqual fails even though the values are the same in python/django

Tags: python, django, testing

Can someone explain why this fails:

```
def test_test(self):
   ...
   print Test.id
   print name[0]
   self.assertEqual(name[0], Test.id)
```

The output is

> Creating test database for alias 'default'... ......
>
> c8124e1d-c01c-4762-bcc0-d32df93e0824
>
> c8124e1d-c01c-4762-bcc0-d32df93e0824 
>   F....................
>   ====================================================================== FAIL: ...
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   ...
>       self.assertEqual(name[0], Test.id)
>
> AssertionError: u'c8124e1d-c01c-4762-bcc0-d32df93e0824' !=
>   UUID('c8124e1d-c01c-4762-bcc0-d32df93e0824')

any ideas?

Comment: They're clearly different kinds of objects entirely, why is this surprising? Have you looked into `UUID`'s `__eq__` implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the error message: `name[0]` is a unicode string and `Test.id` is a UUID. They have the same representation but are different objects. To test equality simply convert one object to the type of the other:

```
self.assertEqual(name[0], str(Test.id))
```